# Change DATETIME FORMAT while fetch foreach

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $sub_array = array();
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_name"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_day"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_start_time"] .' - '. $row["dosen_schedule_end_time"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_quota"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_name"];

        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_degree"];
        
        $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_sumpeserta"];
```

I tried to change `$row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"];` to something like `%d-%m-%Y`

Using something like this `$sub_array[] = date( 'd-m-Y', $row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"])`

But it doesnt work, and then i tried using mySQL

MySQL Query

```
$main_query = "
        SELECT dosen_schedule_table.*, dosen_table.* FROM dosen_schedule_table 
        INNER JOIN dosen_table 
        ON dosen_table.dosen_id = dosen_schedule_table.dosen_id 
        ";
```

And i change it to something like this

```
$main_query = "
        SELECT dosen_schedule_table.*, dosen_table.*, DATE_FORMAT(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart, "%d-%m-%Y") FROM dosen_schedule_table 
        INNER JOIN dosen_table 
        ON dosen_table.dosen_id = dosen_schedule_table.dosen_id 
        ";
```

dosen_schedule_datetimestart sample value 2022-10-15 23:46:59

But apparently it give me an error, is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: In PHP, `"` inside `"` should be escaped. That being said, you actually need to use `'%d-%m-%Y'` instead of `"%d-%m-%Y"`.

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry it was a mySQL DATETIME Format something like 2022-10-15 23:46:59

Comment: `$sub_array[] = (new \DateTimeImmutable($row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"]))->format('d-m-Y');` will solve all your needs (needs to be checked if `dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart` is a nullable field.